# Custom classloader for Hibernate-mapping

Tags: java, classloader, hibernate-mapping

Does anyone know a way to intercept the call Hibernate will make to instantiate a class indicated in a .hbm.xml file?  I need a way to use a custom ClassLoader to provide an instance.  I don't want to change class loading for Hibernate in general, just the instantiate of the mapped "POJO" class.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.foo.Bar" table="Bar">
```

In the example code above, when Hibernate wants to instantiate **Bar** I need to provide that class with custom code instead of relying on the default class loading behavior.

Thanks in advance for any insight,
saethi

Comment: I'm writing an application that wraps Hibernate to communicate with a database.  This application needs to download a .jar file containing updated mappings and POJOs.  The application will then shut down Hibernate and bring it back up using the new mappings and POJOs.  I'm using additional ClassLoader to facilitate the dynamic class loading.  Hopefully that answers your question darioo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the way Hibernate creates entities with a custom `Tuplizer`. See the hibernate documentation, [chapter 4.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-tuplizers).

You can extend `PojoEntityTuplizer`, and override the `buildInstantiator(PersistentClass persistentClass)` method by returning an `Instantiator` instance which builds entities however you prefer.

Comment: This looks really promising; I'll be back soon with the results.  Thanks Flavio!

Comment: This appears to work like a charm.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Note to anyone using this answer, I had to change entity-mode="dynamic-map" from the example to entity-mode="pojo" to get the exact result I was looking for.